# When using \fillwithlines how do you change the vertical space between each line?

Tags: exam

In the code below I get 10cm's worth of ruled lines. How do I control the space between each line?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question what is the time Mr Wolf?
    \fillwithlines{10cm}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setlength\linefillheight{<length>}`. Default is `.25in`. You can also set the line thickness using `\setlength\linefillthickness{<length>}`. Default is `0.1pt`

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}

\setlength\linefillheight{.2in}
\begin{questions}
    \question what is the time Mr Wolf?
    \fillwithlines{10cm}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```